# NSMutableArray to NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsnumber

I have an array that has:

`12,
    "+",
    56,
    "+",
    "",
    "(",
    56,
    "+",
    65,
    ")"`

now let us say i want to add

```
[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex: 1] + [NSMutableArray objectAtIndex: 3]
```

i know i need to convert the array parts to NSNumber, but i can not find anything that says how to do that if thats possible. Also i should add that the numbers are put in as NSString and to change that will be very painful and can be done as a last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a nsnumber from a string like so:

```
NSString *str = @"222";
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[str intValue]];
```

So to convert from an array to an nsnumber:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex: 1] intValue]];
```

But keep in mind that you can't directly add two nsnumber objects together, it would have to be something like this:

```
NSNumber *sum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([one intValue] + [two intValue])];
```

And if you end up using float values, you can just replace `intValue` with `floatValue`

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like

```
NSNumber *number = (NSNumber*)[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:1];
```